# I started getting: Client not authenticated to send mail errors

Tags: c#, authentication, email, office365, smtpclient

I have written several C# apps that used the SmtpClient. they have been running for years. this week they all stopped working and are throwing the following exception:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator.   Source=System.Net.Mail
```

I am not a systems person, but a lowly programmer. I do manage my own Microsoft 365 account and Azure accounts.

in the c# app i am not using default credentials:

```
    using System.Net.Mail;
...
           client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FROM, PW, DOMAIN);
```

In the MS 365 Admin Center when i select Authenticated SMTP i get the following error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter". Error: "Parameter values of type Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter can't be empty. Specify a value, and try again. Parameter name: identity"
```

when i exit my active user and enter it again, all the "Manage email apps" are checked. but i still get the error above and can't send email in my app.

what do i need to do to correct this?

Comment: There are two possibilities.  1) The server was modified to accept only HTTPS and you are sending HTTP. 2) Most Systems have moved from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2.  OAUTH2 is supported on Windows, MAC, and LINUX.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. so if i am using Microsoft 365 Exchange, where should i look first?

Comment: Check the authentication settings on server and see if OAUTH2 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#add-the-pop-imap-or-smtp-permissions-to-your-entra-ad-application

Answer (score 1):

Basic authentication is now disabled in all Office365 tenants. Before December 31 2022, you could re-enable the affected protocols if users and apps in your tenant couldn't connect. Now no one (you or Microsoft support) can re-enable Basic authentication in your tenant. See [Deprecation of Basic authentication in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online) for more information.

`System.Net.Mail` doesn’t support `modern authentication`. Instead, you may consider using a third party SMTP client implementation such as [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene pointed out, modern authentication is no longer supported. SO, i switched to using MailKit. but i still had to disable the TFA on my email account in order to use it, which i did not want to do. So instead, i created a new user with a long un-guessable(?) password to send the emails. it works fine now.
thanks